# Data persistance in cocoa for small amount of data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm busy writing my first cocoa application and I have to store 2 NSStrings somewhere on the hard disc (an username and password). What would be the best way to do this? Just write to a file? And if so, where would be the best place for me to store this file?

I just don't want to use some overkill technique for just 2 simple Strings.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is using **UserDefaults**. It's a place usually used to store application's settings and preferences.

To store a string

```
NSString *user = @"Peter";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"userName"];
```

to get it back later

```
NSString *user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userName"];
```

If you're saving a password, you might consider encrypting it, or instead of storing the password, store the hash for the password.

Comment: Yes, either NSUserDefaults, or use the iOS Keychain to store this data so it's secure, and especially if you need to persist that data if the user deletes the app and reinstalls it at another time. 

Here are the official docs from Apple regarding Keychain services: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

There also several open source libraries/wrappers available for the same.

Comment: Omg... I think I need to go change my pants... Cocoa is awesome!!

Comment: As the updated answer goes, storing the hashed password will also work if that's something you'll be using later anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First encrypt Username and Password strings with MD5, SHA-1 or other algorithm.

After use:

```
NSUserDefaults* prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[prefs setObject:encryptedUsername forKey:@"userName"];
[prefs setObject:encryptedPassword forKey:@"password"];

[prefs synchronize];


// To retrieve info
encryptedUsername = [prefs objectForKey:@"userName"];
encryptedPassword = [prefs objectForKey:@"password"];
```

After encrypt the user input data and compare the encrypted strings.

Comment: This would essentially make the retrieved information useless if the OP needs to use it some place in the app.